# Custom upscale filter in matlab

Tags: matlab, video, image-processing, filter, video-processing

Is it possible to upscale a 960x540 raw video to 1920x1080 using a custom filter in matlab?

The filter I want to use is [1 2 3 3 2 1] 1/12

imresize has custom interpolation kernel but i don't know how to use it with my filter instead of lanczos2 filter.

```
B = imresize(A, [1920 1080], {@lanczos2,4.0} )

function f = lanczos2(x)
f = (sin(pi*x) .* sin(pi*x/2) + eps) ./ ((pi^2 * x.^2 / 2) + eps);
f = f .* (abs(x) < 2);
end
```

Comment: Read the frames from the video and feed them to your custom function? So A would be each video frame.

Comment: I don't know how to write my custom filter function. Above code is an example for lanczos2.

Comment: You need this probably - http://www.mathworks.in/help/images/ref/imfilter.html

Answer (score 1):

You are not thinking about interpolation kernels in the same way as `imresize` is. It requires a function of a real value x, not a discrete-time filter. So you could make such a function, 'mykern.m':

```
function f = mykern(x)
f = (3 - floor(abs(x)))/12 .* double(abs(x) <= 3);
```

and call `imresize(x, 2, {@mykern,6})` on each frame.

If you are confused about how these kernels work, it's useful to plot them:

```
n = -5:.1:5;
figure; plot(n, lanczos2(n));
figure; plot(n, mykern(n));
```

Or, you could avoid using `imresize` by upsampling your image and then filtering it. But in this case you would want to use a 2D filter.

As for reading and writing video, look at the examples for `VideoReader` and `VideoWriter`